# Multiple endpoints in one URL

Tags: wp-query, url-rewriting, endpoints

I am trying to add multiple endpoints in one url like:

http://localhost:1000/manage-lead/lead_id/1000/product_id/123455

But this way the query var `lead_id` is equal to `1000/product/123455` and not `1000`.

When I do it the following way everything goes right:

http://localhost:1000/manage-lead/lead_id/1000/?product_id=123455

So I think that I need to add some rewrite rules, so Wordpress understands that lead_id and product_id are 2 query vars.

**How I add my endpoints:**

```
function add_lead_management_endpoints() {

    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'lead_id', EP_PAGES );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'product_id', EP_PAGES );

}
add_action( 'init', 'add_lead_management_endpoints' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the context for this, is it a custom post type or just a page?

This might be something which you're looking for -

```
function add_lead_management_endpoints() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'manage-lead/lead_id/([0-9]{1,})/product_id/([0-9]{1,})',
        'index.php?pagename=manage-lead&lead_id=$matches[1]&product_id=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );

    add_rewrite_tag( '%lead_id%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%product_id%', '([^&]+)' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_lead_management_endpoints' );
```

You'll need to flush permalinks for this to take affect (visit settings->permalinks).

Comment: Did this resolve your problem @Robbert?

Comment: It did not test i yet, but you asked whether it is a page or post type and I answered page. So does this change anything in your code?

Comment: The above is setup to work with the page ``manage-lead``